# Android - Custom rating bar looks like its bleeding

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

So I have created a rating bar with new icons, however, when I implement it, the stars look like they are bleeding, see attached:

[image: Rating bar]

Here are the style, rating xml, and how they are implemented in the layout:

style:

```
<style name="GoldRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/gold_ratingbar</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/gold_ratingbar</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@null</item>
    <item name="android:isIndicator">true</item>
</style>
```

rating xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/rating_star_icon_off" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/rating_star_icon_half" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/rating_star_icon" />
</layer-list>
```

Layout:

```
<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Overall rating"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/review_overall_rating"
    style="@style/GoldRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:rating="3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/review_rating_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text=""
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had facing same problem.

In my case `blank_star.png` height is 17dp so i put `android:layout_height="17dp"` on `RatingBar` and my problem is resolve.Try below code:-

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    style="@style/rating_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="17dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0" />
```

**style/rating_bar.xml**

```
<style name="rating_bar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar_full</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">18dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">18dip</item>
</style>
```

**drawable/rating_bar_full**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_full_empty"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_full_empty"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_full_filled"/>

</layer-list>
```

**drawable/ratingbar_full_empty**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blank_star" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blank_star" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blank_star" android:state_selected="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blank_star"/>

</selector>
```

**drawable/ratingbar_full_filled.xml**

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/filled_star" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/filled_star" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/filled_star" android:state_selected="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/filled_star"/>
```

Comment: I did try that, but then on the phone, the bottom of the stars is cut off and on a 7" tab, there is about 1 pixel of extra line below the stars. Do you think the images could be wrong?

Comment: reduce image height and cant say image is wrong or what?

Comment: I did reduce the image height, but I can only get it working for the phone or tablet, not both. It always looks incorrect on one

Comment: i suggest u,  use different-2 layouts for supporting UI on both

Answer (score 24):

i had a similar case 
and the accepted answer will not resolve it on all screen sizes
in fact the solution is very simple,
you just need to add padding to the .png image that you are using 
"2 transparent pixels on each side "

the bleeding ocures because android is repeating the last row of your star image so just make this row transparent

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!!! Got looped trying to adjust but the 2pixel transparent padding ON the image did it!!!

Answer (score 8):

For all who are still looking for an answer and don't want to crop the image: `android:minHeight="0dp"` helped me

**Update**.
Why is it working? Well, most of all view components have a default min size to follow accessibility/usability google guidelines. And as was mentioned, seems like `RatingBar` tries to fill the empty space (diff between your own resource and `minHeight`) by repeating the last 1-2 pixels (personally I don't understand the reason of such desicion). So by setting the `android:minHeight="0dp"`, `RatingBar` will wrap content by the height of your resource.

Answer (score 1):

The bleeding occurs because the last row of your star image is being repeated. You could fix this by setting the size of the RatingBar to perfectly match the underlying drawable.

The RatingBar never inspects the size of the underlying drawable. So you have to do this yourself. It can be difficult to do this using xml, since your assets may have different sizes for different screen densities. Plus your UX people may change the assets without updating the xml dimensions.

Solution: create a RatingBar that checks the size of its drawables. See below

```
public class RatingBar extends android.widget.RatingBar {
    private Drawable starDrawable;

    public RatingBar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public RatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        starDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.your_drawable, context.getTheme());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // Make sure to account for padding and margin, if you care.
        // I only cared about left padding.
        setMeasuredDimension(starDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 5 
            + getPaddingLeft(), starDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }
}
```